# "The same X when doing Y as in Z" vs. "the same X as in Z when doing Y"

Tags: conjunctions, placement

I don't know what the proper placement of the conjunction "as" is between "the same X when doing Y as in Z" and "the same X as in Z when doing Y".

Example:

1. [The same X as in Z when doing Y] The model works for all the languages using **the same** patterns **as** in English **when** introducing acronym definitions, which is the case for all Tier 1 languages except Japanese, and most Tier 2 languages.
2. [The same X when doing Y as in Z] The model works for all the languages using **the same** patterns **when** introducing acronym definitions **as** in English, which is the case for all Tier 1 languages except Japanese, and most Tier 2 languages.

Which is the proper placement of "as"? Or are they both correct?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Either works, but you might also say
... using the same patterns as English does in introducing...

It's a long sentence. You might end it after "definitions", and restart with "This is the case for..."

Comment: Thanks for the information and the alternative options!